# What's the difference between Msmq vs .Net Remoting

Tags: msmq

what's the diffence between MSMQ and .net Remoting and which one is better?

Comment: Better for **what**?? What are your criteria?? What is your use case??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I'd use WCF as it is a newer technology and can wrap both... You will find it good enough to meet you criteria / needs.

Comment: You need to press the tick button below the question votes - on the left hand side of the question

Comment: Thank you very much. But how to connect wcf service using tcp protocol. can you send me a demo?